# C# - ModelState is necessary in currently version of C# Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making a POST with the following data to my server:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "usuarioId": 35,
    "titulo": "Testing",
    "descricao": "",
    "valor": 1.11,
    "vencimento": "111111-11-11"
}
```

The expiration property is a Date field in the DTO that is the POST route.

```
public class DespesaDTO
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; } // Chave estrangeira para o usuário
        public string? Titulo { get; set; }
        public string? Descricao { get; set; }
        public double Valor { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="Date")]
        public DateTime Vencimento { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Despesa>> Post(DespesaDTO model) 
{
    try 
    {
        Despesa despesa = _mapper.Map<DespesaDTO, Despesa>(model);
        Usuario usuario = await _unitOfWork.UsuarioRepository.GetByIdAsync(x => x.Id == model.UsuarioId);
                
        if (usuario == null) 
        {
            return NotFound("O usuário informado não existe!");
        }

        despesa.UsuarioId = usuario.Id;

        Console.WriteLine("TEST 2" + despesa);

        _unitOfWork.DespesaRepository.Add(despesa);
        await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();

        DespesaDTO result = _mapper.Map<Despesa, DespesaDTO>(despesa);

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "url": "http://localhost:5241/api/v1/despesa/",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:5241/api/v1/despesa/: 400 Bad Request",
    "error": {
        "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
        "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
        "status": 400,
        "traceId": "00-239d1c05419ba94750eb48062e2509a6-91bebea55feef9cc-00",
        "errors": {
            "model": [
                "The model field is required."
            ],
            "$.vencimento": [
                "The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.vencimento | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 102."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

From what I saw, the error is triggered because what is being sent is not being validated in my DTO, for example the date format in the YEAR part is sending 5 algorithms but it should only contain 4. I would like to know if it is possible to handle this error, to leave it as the default, because when there is an error in the request parameter, it throws this number of properties into my object, if perhaps it would be possible to standardize it to just be

```
error: { message: "text" }
```

Comment: Do u want to format return errors? create a custom exception filter attribute that will catch validation errors and format them as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, It seems you wanna format the error message of 400 error. The default behavior of invalid error is return 400 error directly instead of accessing into the endpoint. SO you can try to configure like this in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(x =>
{
    //....filters.....
}).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(x =>
{
    x.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    };
});
```

Now the error message will be:

[image]

I hope it is what you want.